# Suggestion for this simple SQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with columns like:

| xxx | category_id | product | yyy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Id-1 | Prod-1 |  |
|  | Id-1 | Prod2 |  |
|  | Id-1 | ... |  |
|  | Id-2 | Prod-11 |  |
|  | Id-2 | Prod-1 |  |
|  | ... |  |  |

How do I find if there is any same product (say prod-1 in this example) belongs to 2 category-Ids?

Comment: two category-ids, or *more than one* category-id?

Answer (score 1):

Create a group for each `product` and choose only those groups that have more than one `category_id`:

```
SELECT product
FROM mytable
GROUP BY product
HAVING count(DISTINCT category_id) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```sql
SELECT product 
FROM table as a 
WHERE (SELECT count(DISTINCT category_id) FROM table as b WHERE b.product=a.product) > 1
```